# cURL php post request size limit

Tags: php, curl, post

I've been working with cURL via php for almost a month and successfully send requests from my local server to a remote one but now I'm dealing with some issue I don't know how to fix.

I'm trying to send a encrypted string [containing a json_encode() mysqli query] from my remote server to the local one. The point is this string is **1451045 char long** and saved on a file is equal to **1'39 MB**.

What I want to know is if there's a size limit to the information you send via cURL POST and how to deal with this size limit if that's the solution.

Comment: @B001 maybe. I was looking for an answer but didn't see that question. I'll check it. Thanks!

Comment: there is no size limit on for uploading with curl (short of overflowing the 64bit file position ints at around 18.45 exabytes, i suppose)